# BATCH: TEXT Encryption/Decryption Batch File

Tags: batch-file, encryption

**Hello** **Everyone**,
*In the first place, thank you for taking some time to read this topic as it's my first post in this forum, and I'm also apologizing for my bad English (I'm Moroccan).*

So due to a need in my job I had the obligation to do a TEXT encryption program with batch and I'm not so good at it. I'm supposed to do a small Batch program that asks for a password and encrypts the given text, then create a another batch file for decryption. So basically when you encrypt your text you need to give the other person the password and the decryption batch file. Until that nothing to worry about. But the program needs a new "encryption code" every time like "XXXXX belongs to the letter a".

Now I have two problems. The first one is that I'm having an issue while the program is creating the other batch "the decryption one" file i heard that's the"(" or ")" are the cause of the problem.

My second problem is a little bit harder. I need to know how to compile the second batch file or simply hide its code.

Thank you for reading, here's my code. I hope that you'll find a solution for me.

P.S.: I have two syntax error somewhere I can't find them if someone can find them and correct them for me it'll be really nice. And also why is the last line creating the file DECRYPTED_TEXT? Normally it should just write this line in the Decrypter.Bat File.

```
@echo off
@echo off
title TEXT ENCRYPTER BY YOUHACK
setlocal  ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
color 0A
cls
set string=Loading...
for /L %%a in (1, 1, 11) do (
set sting=!string:~0,%%a! 
echo ^>!sting!
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
if %%a GEQ 11 goto eof
cls 
)
:eof
PING localhost -n 1 >NUL
echo ________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
echo                                              TEXT ENCRYPTER
echo                                                            V 1.0.0
echo                                                                   BY YOUHACK
echo ________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
Pause
if not exist "Output" mkdir Output
cls
   :HInput
   ::Version 3.0     
   SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
Echo Enter Your Password :
   Set "Line="
   Rem Save 0x08 character in BS variable
   For /F %%# In (
   '"Prompt;$H&For %%# in (1) Do Rem"'
   ) Do Set "BS=%%#"

   :HILoop
   Set "Key="
   For /F "delims=" %%# In (
   'Xcopy /L /W "%~f0" "%~f0" 2^>Nul'
   ) Do If Not Defined Key Set "Key=%%#"
   Set "Key=%Key:~-1%"
   SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   If Not Defined Key Goto :HIEnd
   If %BS%==^%Key% (Set /P "=%BS% %BS%" <Nul
   Set "Key="
   If Defined Line Set "Line=!Line:~0,-1!"
   ) Else Set /P "=*" <Nul
   If Not Defined Line (EndLocal &Set "Line=%Key%"
   ) Else For /F delims^=^ eol^= %%# In (
   "!Line!") Do EndLocal &Set "Line=%%#%Key%"
   Goto :HILoop
   :HIEnd
   Echo(
Echo Your Password Is : "%Line%".>Output/ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD.txt
set a=%random%
set b=%random%
set c=%random%
set d=%random%
set e=%random%
set f=%random%
set g=%random%
set h=%random%
set i=%random%
set j=%random%
set k=%random%
set l=%random%
set m=%random%
set n=%random%
set o=%random%
set p=%random%
set q=%random%
set r=%random%
set s=%random%
set t=%random%
set u=%random%
set v=%random%
set w=%random%
set x=%random%
set y=%random%
set z=%random%
set 0=%random%
set 1=%random%
set 2=%random%
set 3=%random%
set 4=%random%
set 5=%random%
set 6=%random%
set 7=%random%
set 8=%random%
set 9=%random%
set @=%random%
set #=%random%
set $=%random%
set *=%random%
set (=%random%
set )=%random%
set .=%random%
set ,=%random%
set -=%random%
set  =%random%
set /=%random%
set \=%random%
set é=%random%
set è=%random%
set à=%random%
(set CHAR[a]=%a%) & (set CHAR[b]=%b%) & (set CHAR[c]=%c%) & (set CHAR[d]=%d%) & (set CHAR[e]=%e%)
(set CHAR[f]=%f%) & (set CHAR[g]=%g%) & (set CHAR[h]=%h%) & (set CHAR[i]=%i%) & (set CHAR[j]=%j%)
(set CHAR[k]=%k%) & (set CHAR[l]=%l%) & (set CHAR[m]=%m%) & (set CHAR[n]=%n%) & (set CHAR[o]=%o%)
(set CHAR[p]=%p%) & (set CHAR[q]=%q%) & (set CHAR[r]=%r%) & (set CHAR[s]=%s%) & (set CHAR[t]=%t%)
(set CHAR[u]=%u%) & (set CHAR[v]=%v%) & (set CHAR[w]=%w%) & (set CHAR[x]=%x%) & (set CHAR[y]=%y%)
(set CHAR[z]=%z%) & (set CHAR[1]=%1%) & (set CHAR[2]=%2%) & (set CHAR[3]=%3%) & (set CHAR[4]=%4%)
(set CHAR[5]=%5%) & (set CHAR[6]=%6%) & (set CHAR[7]=%7%) & (set CHAR[8]=%8%) & (set CHAR[9]=%9%)
(set CHAR[0]=%0%) & (set CHAR[@]=%@%) & (set CHAR[#]=%#%) & (set CHAR[$]=%$%) & (set CHAR[*]=%*%)
(set CHAR[(]=%(%) & (set CHAR[.]=%.%) & (set CHAR[,]=%,%) & (set CHAR[-]=%-%) & (set CHAR[ ]=% %)
(set CHAR[\]=%\%) & (set CHAR[/]=%/%) & (set CHAR[é]=%é%) & (set CHAR[è]=%è%) & (set CHAR[à]=%à%)
cls
echo Enter The Text To Encrypt:
set /p Encrypt=
echo %Encrypt%>Output/UNENCRYPTED_TEXT.txt
cls
set Encrypt2=%Encrypt%
set "EncryptOut="
:encrypt2
set char=%Encrypt2:~0,1%
set Encrypt2=%Encrypt2:~1%
set EncryptOut=%EncryptOut%!CHAR[%char%]!
if not "%Encrypt2%"=="" goto encrypt2
echo Input string: %Encrypt%
echo.
echo Output string: %EncryptOut%
set string=%EncryptOut%
set temp_str=%string%
set str_len=0
:lengthloop
if defined temp_str (
set temp_str=%temp_str:~1%
set /A str_len += 1
goto lengthloop )
echo.
echo Output string is %str_len% characters long.
echo %EncryptOut%>Output/ENCRYPTED_TEXT.txt
echo.
pause
>Output/DECRYPTER.bat (
  Echo @echo off
  ECHO setlocal  ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
  ECHO title TEXT DECRYPTER BY YOUHACK
  ECHO color 0A
  ECHO :MainMenu
  ECHO echo ________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
  ECHO echo                                              TEXT DECRYPTER
  ECHO echo                                                            V 1.0.0
  ECHO echo                                                                   BY YOUHACK
  ECHO echo ________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
  ECHO SET TRUEPASSWORD=%Line%
  ECHO echo Write Your Password Below:
  ECHO set /P Password=
  ECHO IF %%TRUEPASSWORD%%==%%Password%% goto Acess
  ECHO echo Incorrect Password.
  ECHO Pause
  ECHO CLS
  ECHO goto MainMenu
  ECHO :Acess
  ECHO (set CHAR[%a%]=a)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%b%]=b)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%c%]=c)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%d%]=d)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%e%]=e)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%f%]=f)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%g%]=g)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%h%]=h)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%i%]=i)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%j%]=j)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%k%]=k)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%l%]=l)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%m%]=m)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%n%]=n)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%o%]=o)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%p%]=p)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%q%]=q)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%r%]=r)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%s%]=s)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%t%]=t)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%u%]=u)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%v%]=v)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%w%]=w)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%x%]=x)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%y%]=y)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%z%]=z)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%1%]=1)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%2%]=2)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%3%]=3)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%4%]=4)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%5%]=5)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%6%]=6)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%7%]=7)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%8%]=8)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%9%]=9)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%0%]=0)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%@%]=@)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%#%]=#)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%$%]=$)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%*%]=*)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%(%]=()
  ECHO (set CHAR[%.%]=.)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%,%]=,)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%-%]=-)
  ECHO (set CHAR[% %]= )
  ECHO (set CHAR[%\%]=\)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%/%]=/)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%é%]=é)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%è%]=è)
  ECHO (set CHAR[%à%]=à)
  ECHO echo Correct Password .
  ECHO PAUSE
  ECHO echo Enter The Encrypted String To Decrypt:
  ECHO set /p Decrypt=
  ECHO cls
  ECHO set Decrypt2=%Decrypt%
  ECHO set "DecryptOut="
  ECHO :decrypt2
  ECHO set char=%Decrypt2:~0,6%
  ECHO set Decrypt2=%Decrypt2:~6%
  ECHO set DecryptOut=%DecryptOut%!CHAR[%char%]!
  ECHO if not "%Decrypt2%"=="" goto decrypt2
  ECHO echo Encrypted string: %Decrypt%
  ECHO echo.
  ECHO echo Decrypted Text: %DecryptOut%
  ECHO set string=%DecryptOut%
  ECHO set temp_str=%string%
  ECHO set str_len=0
  ECHO :lengthloop
  ECHO if defined temp_str (
  ECHO set temp_str=%temp_str:~1%
  ECHO set /A str_len += 1
  ECHO goto lengthloop )
  ECHO echo.
  ECHO echo The Decrypted Text is %str_len% characters long!
  ECHO echo.%DecryptOut%>>DECRYPTED_TEXT.txt
  ECHO echo.
  ECHO pause
  ECHO cls
)
```

Comment: uh - batch isn't the right tool to do such things. Why not just zip them with a password?

Comment: You cannot use a number as an environmental variable name unless you reference it with delayed expansion.

Comment: [GNUPG](https://www.gnupg.org/) is a freely available encryption program.  Why not use that?

Comment: I know thaht batch isn't much appropriate for suck encryption program but I need to give this program to people so i need it a simple as possible . @Squashman can you explain more please i didn't get you ! thak you for your replies .

Comment: Up ! I Have done it here is the link: [Link](https://mega.nz/#!jUdFkagK) And the Mega Enrecyption Key :"!2GqP7qeeJ0V7Njiuk7PSSVvNJQNepX-Lc74TU7A6ekM" . it's 100% secure No virus . For Anyone Who wants the code contact me in private